# list comprehension (or one-liners) with if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

In python, for iterables many one-line iteration commands can be constructed.

For some of such iterations if-statements are required.

Sometimes the order of if-statement and for-statement is important. 
Suppose I want to find sum of odd numbers between 0 and 10:

```
>>> sum(i if not i%2==0 for i in range(10))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sum(i for i in range(10) if not i%2==0)
25
```

Those one-liners are inherently not very comprehensible, however I don't really understand why the if-statement has to come **after** the for-statement. wouldn't it more fit common sense to use the previous `i if not i%2==0 for i in range(10)`?

Comment: Why are you writing `not i%2 == 0` instead of `i%2 != 0`?

Comment: "those one-liners are inherently not comprehensible" is a pretty severe blanket statement.  In point of fact, they're quite comprehensible, and extremely powerful.

Comment: You are effectively saying "as it stands, the python syntax for list comprehensions is not very comprehensible. Shouldn't we change it to be this other way?". Well, there are tons of people using that feature of python successfully; so it /is/ comprehensible. If you don't like it, well, you could always modify the parser for yourself and propose it as a PEP. Of course, you're always welcome to find/invent a language that allows you to express list comprehensions your way.

Answer (score 5):

In a generator expression (or a list comprehension), the statements should be listed as if you were nesting them.

Your `sum()` expression can be nested as:

```
for i in range(10):
    if not i%2 == 0:
        # do something with i
```

You cannot change that ordering, the following would not make sense since `i` is not defined:

```
if not i%2 == 0:
    for i in range(10):
        # do something with i
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you have an unconditional loop with an if-expression as the list comprehension value. The correct syntax would be:

```
(a if b else c for i in iterable)
 \___________/
    |
   actual expression
```

`a if b else c` is equivalent to `a` if `b` evaluates to true, and `c` otherwise.

In your second example, you have a conditional list comprehension. You are basically skipping over values from the iterable; or more precisely, you are specifying which are taken:

```
(a for i in iterable if <condition>)
```

In case of a sum, you can rewrite your list comprehension using the first syntax, as zero is a null element for the addition (and as such the sum):

```
sum(i if i % 2 != 0 else 0 for i in range(10))
```